# WPF DataGrid custom sort: reorder items in ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid, datatable, dataview

I have my custom grid which inherits from `DataGrid` (from WPFToolkit) that has around 10000 items in it. The built-in sort is very slow. As such I have written a separate class that keeps a running sort of all the `DataRowView` items for each column (this works because additions and removals from the grid are extremely seldom, if ever).

The grid has `AutoGenerateColumns='True'` and is bound to the `DefaultView` of a `DataTable`.

I override the `OnSorting` to know when a column header is clicked and try to replace the `ItemsSource` of the grid with my sorted list of DataRowView. Below is the method:

```
    private void RefreshItems()
    {
        if (_updating || _multiIndexer.Count == 0)
            return;

        try
        {
            _updating = true;
            this.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            // replace the itemssource with my maintained and sorted list of 
            // DataRowView items
            this.ItemsSource = _multiIndexer.ToList();
        }
        finally
        {
            //this.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            _updating = false;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I destroy the columns that existed from the auto-generation. Also, I'm only left with columns that match the properties from `DataRowView`.

I believe the best approach would be to create a `DataView` from my sorted list of `DataRowView` and pass that to the `ItemsSource` but I have yet to have any success.

Any ideas how to pass a new list of rows to the ItemsSource or Items without destroying the auto-generated columns? Generating all my columns manually is not an option.

Cheers,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to get rid of re-creation of the columns. I'm having a similar problem, and usually I'm using ICollectionView and DeferRefresh. Because you don't have to do it in your actual model object. But I'm not sure if it works with DataViews as well as good as with List.

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "its very slow"?

if i take a datagrid and bind a datatable with 50000row and 20columns to it. it seems fast to me

viewmodel

```
public class Viewmodel
{
    public DataTable MyData { get; set; }

    public Viewmodel()
    {
        this.MyData = new DataTable();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            this.MyData.Columns.Add("Col" + i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
        {
            var row = MyData.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {

                row["Col" + j] = string.Format("{0} Row, Col {1}", i, j);
            }
            this.MyData.Rows.Add(row);

        }
    }
}
```

window

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">

    </DataGrid>
```

edit: its .net4.0

Comment: as soon as we start sorting by multiple columns in both directions, the built-in sort becomes very slow. the algo we've chosen is between 4-10 times faster to build the sorted list of datarows to display (compared to the time taken by the grid to complete its own sorting but without displaying this list... so i'm still not sure if the results hold true). this is why i need to display the list of datarows i've got without destroying or rebuilding the columns